# What does it mean when a number 'y' is pseudoprime to base 'x'

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pseudoprimes

I am self learner so I don't really understand about pseudoprime to base $x$

> For example, $91$ is a pseudoprime to base $3$ then is $91$ also a
>   pseudoprime to base $2$?

thank you please explain.

edit** I did a bit research

> For example, an odd composite integer $N$ will be called a Fermat
>   pseudoprime to base $a$, if $\gcd(a, N) = 1$ and $a^{N−1} \equiv 1 \pmod{N}$.

My question is what about base $2$? Do we use the same formula like $2^{90}$ and divide by $91$? If I don't get a remainder as $1$, it is not a pseudoprime, right? But when I plugged in on the calculator, the number is too big so how can I find a remainder on calculator?

Comment: Google first hit for "pseudoprime": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime . Note that most commonly Fermat's pseudoprimes are meant.

Comment: Based on your edit: What is your actual question now? The wiki page seems to answer your question completely. So please edit the question and clarify **what exactly** is unclear to you on the wiki page.

Comment: what about base 2? do we use the same formula like $2^9^0$   and divide by 91? if I don't get a remainder as 1 so it is not a pseudoprime right? but when I plugged in on the calculator, the number is too big so how can I find a remainder on calculator?

Comment: Note that every odd number is a $2$-pseudoprime and no even number is a $2$-pseudoprime. You can compute $a^{n-1} \bmod a$ by multiplying by $a$ and taking modulo $a$ in each step, this way you never work with numbers larger than $a^2$. You also have, for instance $a^{90}=a^{64}a^{16}a^{8}a^{2}$, which allows to compute $a^{n-1}\bmod a$ very fast (in $O(\log n)$).

Comment: (i)...If $B,C$ are co-prime and $A\equiv 1 \mod B$ and $A\equiv 1 \mod C$ then $A\equiv 1  \mod (BC)$...  (ii)...Since $7$ and $13$ are primes and $2$ is co-prime to each of them we have $2^{12}\equiv (2^6)^2\equiv 1^2\equiv 1 \mod 7$ and $2^{12}\equiv 1 \mod 13$, so by (i), $2^{12}\equiv 1 \mod (7\cdot 13)$...(iii)... Hence mod $91$ we have $2^{90}\equiv (2^{12})^72^6\equiv 1^7 2^6\equiv 2^6 \not \equiv 1$.....BTW the least composite $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $2^{n-1}\equiv 1 \mod n$ is $n=341=(11)(31).$

Answer (score 0):

To calculate powers modulo $n$ you can use [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), i. e. reduce the results of multiplications or exponentiations modulo $n$ so that the numbers do not get too big.

If you want to use a calculator for $2^{90} mod\ 91$ you can split $90$ into factors $10\cdot3\cdot3$ and use the formula $x^{(a*b)} = (x^a)^b$:

1. calculate $2^{10} = 1024$ and subtract $1001$ which is a multiple of $91$, result: $23 = 2^{10} mod \ 91$
2. calculate $23^3 = 12167$ and subtract $133\cdot91$, result: $64 = (2^{10})^3 mod \ 91$
3. calculate $64^3 = 262144$ and subtract $2880\cdot 91$, result: $64 = ((2^{10})^3)^3 mod \ 91 = 2^{90} \ mod \ 91$.

$ \Rightarrow 91 $ is not a pseudoprime base 2.

Subtraction of any multiples of 91 (or n in the general case) from intermediate results does not change the final result as long as the numbers are small enough for the required exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of familiarity, let's suppose that you have a large number $n$ written in base ten, and want to know if it's a prime number.  A simple test is to look at the last digit.

- If it's 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8, then $n$ is a multiple of 2 (aka “even”), so not prime.
- If it's 0 or 5, then $n$ is a multiple of 5, so not prime.
- If it's 1, 3, 7, or 9, then $n$ **could** be a prime.

(Note that this test doesn't work for $2$ and $5$ themselves, so these have to be treated as special cases.)

Of course, not all numbers with a last digit of 1, 3, 7, or 9 actually are prime.  Counterexamples include 21, 27, and 33.

You may have learned [the divisibility rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) for 9: A number is divisible by 9 if the sum of its digits is divisible by 9.  This works because $\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : 10^n ≡ 1\pmod{9}$.  This sum-of-digits rule also works to check divisibility by 3, which is a factor of 9.  For example, 57 has the digit sum $5 + 7 = 12$, which is divisible by 3, and therefore 57 itself is divisible by 3 (in fact, $57 = 3 \times 19$).

Applying this divisible-by-3 test correctly identifies 21, 27, and 33 as being composite, but still fails for 49, 77, and 91.

If you treat each *pair* of base-ten digits as a base-100 “digit”, a number's base-100 digit sum will be congruent to its remainder modulo $10^2 - 1 = 99 = 3^2 \times 11$.  We already have a rule for divisibility by 3, but have gained a rule for divisibility by 11.

Applying this divisible-by-11 test correctly identifies 77, 121, and 143 as being composite, but still fails for 49, 91, and 119.

Let's extend our digit grouping to groups of *three* base-ten digits, giving base-1000 digits.  A number's base-1000 digit sum is congruent to its remainder modulo $10^3 = 999 = 3^3 \times 37$, giving us a rule for divisibility by 37.

Applying this divisibile-by-37 test correctly identities 259, 481, and 629 as being composite, but still fails for 49, 91, and 119.

We can extend this digit-grouping logic to factors of $10^4 - 1 = 9999$, $10^5 - 1 = 99999$, $10^6 - 1 = 999999$, etc.  We can go all the way up to factors of $10^{N-1} - 1$, where $N$ is the number we're testing.  If $N$ still fails the test, then that's a pretty good indication that it's prime.  But *not* a certainty.

This concept can be generalized to other number bases.  For example, in base-12, all numbers (besides 2 and 3) with a last digit of 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, or A (ten) are divisible by 2; and all numbers with a last digit of 0, 3, 6, or 9 are divisible by 3; leaving numbers with a last digit of 1, 5, 7, or B (eleven) as potentially prime.  And we can construct sum-of-grouped-digits rules for divisibility by $12^1 - 1 = 11$, $12^2 - 1 = 143 = 11 \times 13$, $12^3 - 1 = 1727 = 11 \times 157$, $12^4 - 1 = 20735 = 5 \times 11 \times 13 \times 29$ etc.

---

Of course, you can always just brute-force all potential divisors between $2$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor$ to check if $N$ actually *is* prime.  Problem is, when $N$ is extremely large, all that division takes a long time, even for a computer.  So it helps to have a shortcut that filters out definitely composite numbers before we go through the full effort of checking if $N$ is really a prime.

For example, you could just check if $\gcd(a, N) = 1$ (which is really a last-digit test) and $a^{N−1} \equiv 1 \pmod{N}$ (which is really a sum-of-grouped-digits test), giving you the **Fermat pseudoprimes to base $a$**, as defined in your question.  In base ten, Fermat's primality test gives false positives for 9, 33, 91, etc. ([OEIS A005939](https://oeis.org/A005939)).

In general, a **pseudoprime** is a number that “looks prime” but might not be.  The term can be defined in many ways, depending on which specific divisibility tests you use.  But Fermat's is the most common definition.

---

> But when I plugged in on the calculator, the number is too big so how can I find a remainder on calculator?

Depends on your calculator.  In many programming languages, [the modulo/remainder operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) is spelled `%`, `mod` (for modulo), or `rem` (for remainder).  If your calculator doesn't provide such an operator, you can use the identity:

$$a \operatorname{mod} b = a - \lfloor a/b \rfloor$$

If you don't have [a floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) either, get a better calculator.  Or copy the part of `a/b` before the decimal point.

It helps if you have [arbitrary-precision numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) available.  This is a preinstalled feature in the TI-89/92 computer algebra system, and in the Python programming language (with `int` for integers (or `long` before 3.0), and `fractions.Fraction` for rationals).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. If nothing else is said, it is assumed that *pseudoprime* means *Fermat's pseudoprime*, i.e., a number $n$ such that $a^{n-1}\equiv1\bmod{a}$. The number $a$ is the base here, so *pseudoprime w.r.t. base $3$* is a number such that $3^{n-1}\equiv1\bmod 3$.

We call it a pseudoprime, because all primes are pseudoprimes w.r.t. all bases (but not vice versa, as you realized).